# php-intl conflicts with custom Locale class

Tags: php, internationalization, php-5.5

I am working on a website and some pages doesn't work after installing php5-intl library on the server. After some hours of debugging I 've found out that the problem is the name of a class in codes which is named Locale.

Is there any other solution rather than renaming the class?

Comment: You'll either need to rename it or (ideally) move it into your own namespace. This is really what namespaces are designed for.

Comment: @iainn thank you. codes of website is developed many year ago before and there aren't any usage of namespace in it. So I have to add namespace to every class inside it?

Comment: Well it doesn't **have** to be every class, but you'll definitely need to deal with the `Locale` one. It's good practice for the namespaces to match the directory structure, but there's no requirement for it. Renaming might be easier in your circumstances - if you're dealing with a huge legacy codebase then it might be a bit weird to just have one class in a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a namespace conflict. You have a class called Locale? Give it a namespace:

```
<?php

namespace My;

class Locale
{
   //
}
```

Then you can say:

```
use My\Locale;
```

If you ever have code that uses BOTH classes, you can alias one:

```
use Locale;
use My\Locale as MyLocale;
```

Then you can say `new MyLocale();` and there won't be a conflict.
Hope this helps!